Error getting Firebase authentication token
Fixed
On my android project I tried to test crash and I got warning on my logcat,
I have been experiencing this since October 1st, when i see my credentials at console.cloud.google it shows that Firebase generate another credentials. If I get google-service.json file from console.firebase.google it shows two credentials which should be only one and the new was auto generated by Firebase.
Full logcat
 Error getting Firebase authentication token.
                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
                    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.Utils.awaitEvenIfOnMainThread(Utils.java:132)
                    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.IdManager.fetchTrueFid(IdManager.java:186)
                    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.SessionReportingCoordinator.ensureHasFid(SessionReportingCoordinator.java:246)
                    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.SessionReportingCoordinator.sendReports(SessionReportingCoordinator.java:228)
                    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$2$1.then(CrashlyticsController.java:246)
                    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$2$1.then(CrashlyticsController.java:233)
                    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzo.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:1)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:67)
                    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
                 Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
                    at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.createFirebaseInstallation(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:153)
                    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.registerFidWithServer(FirebaseInstallations.java:533)
                    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary(FirebaseInstallations.java:387)
                    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationOrRefresh$3$com-google-firebase-installations-FirebaseInstallations(FirebaseInstallations.java:372)
                    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
                    at com.google.firebase.concurrent.SequentialExecutor$1.run(SequentialExecutor.java:117)
                    at com.google.firebase.concurrent.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:229)
                    at com.google.firebase.concurrent.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java:174)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                    at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0$com-google-firebase-concurrent-CustomThreadFactory(CustomThreadFactory.java:47)
                    at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 

but, on my Firebase Crashlytics, still get the data from the test crash

Previoustly my project was fine and no warning from firebase. I expected no warning from firebase.
Edit: I tried to add Android restriction and forget to add the debug version on console.cloud.google in the credentials section. After I add that, it fixed.
